# jQuery animation unexpected lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to create a "hover" effect with jQuery.
It works fine except for a strange lag occuring only the first time the complete callback is called - I noticed it is the *only* time it actually reaches the exact position it should (rest are ~1px less, but that's fine), stays there for a bit, then continues the animation and from that point it works smoothly.

I've created a jsFiddle with my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4dkB/1/) and this is the code I've written.

```
function hover(el, speed, start, stop) {
    if (el.is(':visible')) {
        el.animate({
            'top': stop + 'px'
        }, speed, function () {
            el.animate({
                'top': start + 'px'
            }, speed, hover(el, speed, start, stop));
        });
    }
}

$("div > div").fadeIn(1000, function () {
    hover($(this), 1000, 192, 210);
});
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is it a bug? Am I misusing something?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would you consider a pure CSS solution or is jQuery required?

Comment: I considered this, but dropped the idea for older browser support.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you need more of jQuery's functionality than just animations?

Comment: I use it throughout the site, yes.

Comment: OK. If you were just using jQuery for animations, then I would have highly recommended replacing it with [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/)

Comment: I'd probably go for vanilla JS for a single function, but thanks for the suggestion, I will surely check it out, since it looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lag is caused because in the second call of the hover() function your element is already in top: 210px so it just wait 1sec for nothing , to fix this just switch start and stop points in your function

```
function hover(el, speed, start, stop) {
    if (el.is(':visible')) {
        el.animate({
            'top': start + 'px'
        }, speed, function () {
            el.animate({
                'top': stop + 'px'
            }, speed, hover(el, speed, start, stop));
        });
    }
}
```

so the lag will be in the start and won't get noticed

**EDIT**

a workaround is to give it a kick in the first time :

```
var firstTime = true ; //this is global
function hover(el, speed, start, stop) {
    if (el.is(':visible')) {
        el.animate({
            'top': start + 'px'
        }, speed, function () {
            if(firstTime){
            el.animate({'top' : stop +"px" } , speed , function(){
                //something here 
            });
            firstTime = false; 
        }
        el.animate({
                'top': stop + 'px'
            }, speed, hover(el, speed, start , stop));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution and made me understand the problem, I'd rather, though, get a solution without any lag - beginning or end. I am also curious about why are further animation smooth.

Comment: I guess there's no way to avoid an extra flag. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS Animations

```
@-webkit-keyframes oscillation {
    from { top:192px; }
    to{ top:210px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes oscillation {
    from { top:192px; }
    to{ top:210px; }
}
```

Following that just put this in your CSS for `div > div`:

```
-webkit-animation: oscillation 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: oscillation 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
```

#### Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/F4dkB/3/